# CSS- text-decoration problems

Tags: html, css

So I will apologize in advance if this question has already been asked, but I will mention it anyway. Basically there is a problem with an HTML document that I have been working on. I set a rule for the links in the span tags for every different link, because I want them to have different text-decoration properties, and it doesn't seem to apply them. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> MSCC Software </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mscccss.css">
  </head>
  <body> <!-- I will do an early apology if there is any bad code -->
    <div id="header">
      <p id="topline"> MSCC Software </p> 
      <p id="bottomline"> www.mscc.com </p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"> 
      <span id="google"> <a href="http://www.google.com"> Google</a> </span>
      <span id="example"> <a href="http://www.example.com"> Example </a> </span>
      <span id="debt"> <a href="http://www.usadebtclock.org"> Debt </a> </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p> Happy Holidays </p>
      <img src="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/12/12626-illustration-of-a-decorated-christmas-tree-pv.png"  />
      <p> From MSCC! </p>
    </div>
    <p id="credit"> Created By PharellPharell </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now my CSS:

```
    body{
    height: 970px;
    background-color: rgba:(223,223,223,80%);
    font-family: Verdana;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}


#header{
    height: 12%;
    border: solid red;
    background-color: rgb(127,0,0);
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFA7C;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#topline{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


#bottomline{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#sidebar{
    height: 75%;
    width: 15%;
    border: solid red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(127,0,0);
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#google{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #EC00BC;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#example{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #EC00BC;
    text-decoration: overline;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#debt{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(7,239,20);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content{
    height: 75%;
    width: 77%;
    background-color: rgba(0,119,31,0.9);
    border: solid rgb(127,0,0);
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: rgb(127,0,0);
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center; 
    float: right;
} 

img{
    height: 300px;
}

#credit{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgb(127,0,0);
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-left: 550px;
}
```

So yeah, that is basically it. I can't figure out what to do about it, and if I'm making a stupid mistake, I apologize. Help would be appreciated for this,

Thanks so much!

BTW. Fun fact- PharellPharell is my GitHub username, you can find me on there if you want to look me up.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be targeting the `a` tags instead of just the `span` they are wrapped in.  For example:

```
#google a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Quit looking, answer is here.

Comment: Ok, I made the change, but now for the main content, the div and all of the formatting dissappeared! How did this happen?

Comment: Never mind, fixed it. I used a > with the a tag to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to remove the text-decoration from **all** the links on the site, which will allow the more specific rules to take precedence.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```